# Python DataFrame Combine Two Columns with type pandas.core.series.Series into a Single Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to combine these two columns to a new column by elements in pandas, for example, the first row should become:

```
['332', '331'] + ['C/A/2/3', 'C/A/2/3']  = ['332C/A/2/3', '331C/A/2/3']
```

This is a large dataset, so a faster method would save a lot of time.
the columns in the dataset are

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the two columns, then [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the zipped entries :

```
mapping = {'stops': [['332', '331'],
  ['327', '331', '332'],
  ['015', '014', '013', '012', '011'],
  ['011', '013', '014', '015'],
  ['148', '161']],
 'routes': [['C/A/2/3', 'C/A/2/3'],
  ['2/3', '2/3', '2/3'],
  ['N/R', 'N/R', 'N/R', 'N/R', 'N/R'],
  ['N/R', 'N/R', 'N/R', 'N/R'],
  ['C/A/1', 'C/A/1']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mapping)

df['merged'] = [["".join(entry) for entry in zip(*ent)] 
                for ent in zip(df.stops, df.routes)]
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done like this also

```
stops_routes=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):    #loop over all the rows
    lst=[]
    for j in range(len(df['stops'][i])):     #as their are variable number of elements in every rows
        lst.append(df['stops'][i][j]+df['routes'][i][j])      #add the elements(that are string) inside the list
    stops_routes.append(lst)     #append it to out final list this happens for every row


df['stops_routes']=stops_routes     #creating a new column as stops_routes in the data frame and giving the values to the column
```

I have tried to explain every line of code using comments.